# Android - How can I work with ActionBar in Delphi XE5 app

Tags: android, delphi, android-actionbar, delphi-xe5

I think, I need to extend `ActionBarActivity`. But I can't extend android activity in Delphi XE5.
Are there other ways to add this feature (Action Bar with icons) to the app window?

Comment: what may be unclear in the question which already has an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of an actionbar in delphi. However, you could use a toolbar and add speedbuttons and a label. By changing the stylelookup of the speedbutton you can pick from a set of predefined images in the android style. That works for me.

Comment: I've also thought to use `TToolBar` after I asked question. It seems to work therefore your answer is correct.